# Find duplicate email with jquery validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, validation

I have a sign-up page where I validate all the field entries with [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). How can I use jquery to validate my form to check for duplicates in my mysql database? I tried to use remote method but nothing happens when I type an email which is already in database.

**sign_up.php**

```
$("#feedbackForm").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "inc/check_email.php"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            email: "Insert valid adress",
            required: "Please complete email field",
            remote: "Email is already in use, please change it."
        }
    }
});
```

**/inc/check_email.php**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE email  = '" . $email . "'");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the plugin is expecting a JSON. `true/false` aren't returned properly via an axaj call

Comment: Use the $.validator.addMethod in jQuery

Comment: You must return "true" or "false" instead of true or false. The return must be at a json format like Robert says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin was expecting a JSON, thanks everyone.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
echo json_encode(FALSE);
} else{
echo json_encode(TRUE); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements, using the default error message. If the serverside response is a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead", this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default.

So you need to change your if to:

```
$array = ['email' => 'true'];
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
   $array['email'] = 'Email is duplicated';
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Moreover, you should change your db engine to pdo or mysqli. Mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

see this url

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/ajaxSubmit-integration-demo.html

```
jQuery(function() {
        $.mockjax({
            url: "login.action",
            response: function(settings) {
                var user = settings.data.match(/user=(.+?)($|&)/)[1],
                    password = settings.data.match(/password=(.+?)($|&)/)[1];
                if (password !== "foobar") {
                    this.responseText = "Your password is wrong (must be foobar).";
                    return;
                }
                this.responseText = "Hi " + user + ", welcome back.";
            },
            responseStatus: 200,
            responseTime: 500
        });

        // show a simple loading indicator
        var loader = jQuery('<div id="loader"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading..."></div>')
            .css({
                position: "relative",
                top: "1em",
                left: "25em",
                display: "inline"
            })
            .appendTo("body")
            .hide();
        jQuery().ajaxStart(function() {
            loader.show();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            loader.hide();
        }).ajaxError(function(a, b, e) {
            throw e;
        });

        var v = jQuery("#form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    target: "#result"
                });
            }
        });

        jQuery("#reset").click(function() {
            v.resetForm();
        });
    });
```